# CSS and Images does not appear on Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

i write some stuff on spring mvc and i got this in configuration file

```
 @RequestMapping(value={"/userPage"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userPageController (Model model, Principal principal) {
        username = principal.getName();
        Set<Mesurements> mesurements = java.util.Collections.EMPTY_SET;
        mesurements =  measurementsDAO.findUserMesur(username);

        model.addAttribute("user", username);
        model.addAttribute("mesurements", mesurements);
        return "userPage";      
  } 

   @RequestMapping(value={"/userPage/addProject"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String addProjectController (Model model, Principal principal) {
        model.addAttribute("user", username);
        return "addProject";      
  }    `
```

so when i move to 8084/Grad/userPage.htm everything (css, images) appears,
but when i move to 8084/Grad/userPage/addProject.htm nothing from css or images appears

Can anyone help? thenx

Comment: Please provide your resource handler configuration. If you don't know what that is, provide your full servlet context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add registry Resource handler as follows

```
/**
 * @param registry Resource handler registry
 * @see WebMvcConfigurationSupport#addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry)
 */
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    logger.info("Adding resources handlers");
    final String[] RESOURCES = { "/resources/**" };

    registry.addResourceHandler(RESOURCES).addResourceLocations(RESOURCES).setCachePeriod(86400);
}
```